# How can I prevent search value in pagination in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, search, pagination

I have code for pagination. and it is working fine. 
but I have added functionality for search.
so the problem is that when i press submit button it shows search result with paging.
and when I click on page number page gets refreshed and grid has all default values, it losts the search name.

So how can I prevent searchname throughout page nevigation? If I use session then when could I wite into session and when to delete session?

my code for fetching all product is like:

```
     $data = $this->paginate('Product');
     $this->set("Products",$data);
```

and by condition is like:

```
   $productname = $this->data['User']['search'];
   $productname = trim($productname);

   $cond = array('Product.productname LIKE' => "%$productname%"); 
   $this->set('Products', $this->paginate("Product", $cond));
```

So can I solve my problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your search request to the parameters like this

```
$this->params['named']['search'] = urlencode(json_encode($productname));
```

The productname will then be available when navigating through the pages (check the URL, you will see your request). Then, you can retrieve the requested product by looking at the params array.

```
if (isset($this->params['named']['search'])) {
  $productname = json_decode(urldecode($this->params['named']['search']));
  // ...
}
```

**EDIT : example**

```
// inside the index action

if (isset($this->data['User']['search'])) {
    $productname = $this->data['User']['search'];
    $productname = trim($productname);
    $this->params['named']['search'] = urlencode(json_encode($productname));
}

$cond = array();

if (isset($this->params['named']['search'])) {
    $productname = json_decode(urldecode($this->params['named']['search']));
    $cond = array('Product.productname LIKE' => "%$productname%");
}

$this->set('Products', $this->paginate("Product", $cond));
```

Comment: you should pass those text values base64encoded. it can fail hard with some special chars in it (+ / etc). the official cakedc search plugin even had a bug the size of a tennis court in that area. so better safe than sry.

Comment: the fix is here: https://github.com/dereuromark/search/commit/c7106020848133aa991956529a8fd308bad7bdeb - anyway @dolly: if you want to use the search more often and extensive, you might want to look into this plugin as it handles this quite well.

Comment: @dolly Il could be placed in many different places. In your action would be fine. I'm going to edit my answer to show you an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add pagination with search name

**In your controller**

```
<?php

$separator = array();
$urlSeparator = array();
$search_keyword = '';
$cond = array();

/* if user enter search keyword then  */
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
 if (isset($this->request->data['User']['Search']) && ($this->request->data['User']['Search'] != '')) {
    $search_keyword = $this->request->data['User']['Search'];
}
}
/*if search keyword is not enter then look for pagination condition params*/
elseif (!empty($this->request->params['named']['cond'])) {

$this->request->params['named']['cond'] = strtr($this->request->params['named']['cond'], '-_, ', '+/=');

$this->request->params['named']['cond'] = json_decode(base64_decode($this->request->params['named']['cond']), true);
    if (isset($this->request->params['named']['cond']['search_keyword']) &&   $this->request->params['named']['cond']['gender'] != '') {
    $search_keyword = trim($this->request->params['named']['cond']['search_keyword']);
 }
}

if(!empty($search_keyword)){
 $cond[] = "Product.productname LIKE '%" . $search_keyword . "'";
 $separator['search_keyword'] = $search_keyword;
}


if (!empty($this->request->params)) {
   if (isset($this->request->params["named"]["page"])) {
    $urlSeparator[] = 'page:' . $this->request->params["named"]["page"];
   }
   if (isset($this->request->params["named"]["sort"])) {
    $urlSeparator[] = 'sort:' . $this->request->params["named"]["sort"];
   }
   if (isset($this->request->params["named"]["direction"])) {
    $urlSeparator[] = 'direction:' . $this->request->params["named"]["direction"];
  }
}

$urlSeparator = implode("/", $urlSeparator);
$this->set('separator', $separator);
$this->set('urlSeparator', $urlSeparator);

$this->set('Products', $this->paginate("Product", $cond));

?>
```

**and in view file add given below code.**

```
<?php
$this->Paginator->options(array('update' => '#div_id_for_update',
    'url' => array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'index', "cond" => strtr(base64_encode(json_encode($separator)), '+/=', '-_,')),
));
?>
```

Please modify above code according your controller name.